# Many Replace after each other in SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a column that have a varchar2 like this: ..x...y...z..

> I want to replace x to 1, y to 2 and z to 3.

Is it possible to have multiple replace after each other in select statement to replace these characters?

```
(select)

replace(varchar2, 'x', '1')
replace(varchar2, 'y', '2')
replace(varchar2, 'z', '3')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
replace(replace(replace(varchar2, 'x', '1'), 'y', '2'), 'z', '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use TRANSLATE function if that fits your needs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145